# Generating lists from dataframes for function calls and the function calls then return unknown index and logical errors

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am new to R and trying generate bioinformatics data visualizations called dendrograms (16S rRNA trees) to show the relationship between select genomes.

I start by importing the library and the packages I need and reading .csv files that contain lists of the accession numbers for those genomes in the GenBank database. 3 different sets of genomes are read into 3 dataframes. I then put each of these 3 data frames contents into lists so I can use the RNA tree-building function ("dendrogram16S()") to read the lists and generate the dendrograms/trees.

My problem is I don't understand what to do when my code returns warnings about "no such index at level 1" and "recursive indexing failed at level 2". The code below shows errors related to "no such index at level 1" instead of "recursive indexing failed at level 2" because the error out put varies depending on if I run the code once or twice.

Here is my code:

```
setwd("/Users/adamstark/BMIG_5101")

ls("package:RBiotools")
lsf.str("package:RBiotools")

library(msa)
library(installr)

# import genome list accession #'s file
single_sp_data <- read.csv("genome_list_single_species_yersinia_pestis_strains.csv", fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")
single_sp_data

multi_sp_data <- read.csv("genome_list_multiple_species_genomes.csv", fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")
multi_sp_data

comb_sp_data <- read.csv("combined_single_and_multi_species_genome_list.csv", fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")
comb_sp_data                                                                      

# put accession #'s into df to make a list for RBiotools
df1=single_sp_data
access_nums1=list()
for(i in 1:ncol(df1)) {access_nums1[[i]] <- df1[ , i]}
names(access_nums1)=colnames(df1)
print(access_nums1)

df2=multi_sp_data
access_nums2=list()
for(i in 1:ncol(df2)) {access_nums2[[i]] <- df2[ , i]}
names(access_nums2)=colnames(df2)
print(access_nums2)

df3=comb_sp_data
access_nums3=list()
for(i in 1:ncol(df3)) {access_nums3[[i]] <- df3[ , i]}
names(access_nums3)=colnames(df3)
print(access_nums3)

# load accession #'s list into RBiotools; get associated organism data
library(RBiotools)
downloadGenome(access_nums1)
downloadGenome(access_nums2)
downloadGenome(access_nums3)

#creating 16sRNA trees

dendrogram16S(access_nums1[1],
              treeType = "BEST",
              leafLabel = "shortName",
              plotIdentifier = "Single Species Genomes")

dendrogram16S(access_nums2[2],
              treeType = "BEST",
              leafLabel = "shortName",
              plotIdentifier = "Diverse Organism Genomes")

dendrogram16S(access_nums3[3],
              treeType = ,
              leafLabel = ,
              plotIdentifier = "Single Species/Diverse Organism Combined Genomes")
```

The code works to create the data frames:

```
> # put accession #'s into df to make a list for RBiotools
> df1=read.csv("genome_list_single_species_yersinia_pestis_strains.csv")
> access_nums1=list()
> for(i in 1:ncol(df1)) {access_nums1[[i]] <- df1[ , i]}
> names(access_nums1)=colnames(df1)
> print(access_nums1)
$AE017042
 [1] "CP033699"   "CP009785.1" "CP009492.1" "CP009723.1" "CP009844.1"
 [6] "CP064123.1" "CP002956"   "CP064125"   "CP064119.2" "CP064122.2"
[11] "CP064127"   "CP064124.1" "CP064126.1" "CP064118.1" "CP064120.1"
[16] "CP064128.1" "AL590842.1" "AE009952.1"

> 
> df2=read.csv("genome_list_multiple_species_genomes.csv")
> access_nums2=list()
> for(i in 1:ncol(df2)) {access_nums2[[i]] <- df2[ , i]}
> names(access_nums2)=colnames(df2)
> print(access_nums2)
$CP020414
 [1] "AE017125"   "AL450380"   "CP007027.1" "AL123456.3" "AP018036"  
 [6] "AP017922"   "CP007224"   "AP014696"   "BA000016.3" "HF930131"  
[11] "CP026932"   "AE014074"   "AE009949.1" "AP014596.1" "CP027540"  
[16] "CP066168"   "AP007209.1" "AE014613"   "AL157959"  

> 
> df3=read.csv("combined_single_and_multi_species_genome_list.csv")
> access_nums3=list()
> for(i in 1:ncol(df3)) {access_nums3[[i]] <- df3[ , i]}
> names(access_nums3)=colnames(df3)
> print(access_nums3)
$AE017042
 [1] "CP033699"   "CP009785.1" "CP009492.1" "CP009723.1" "CP009844.1"
 [6] "CP064123.1" "CP002956"   "CP064125"   "CP064119.2" "CP064122.2"
[11] "CP064127"   "CP064124.1" "CP064126.1" "CP064118.1" "CP064120.1"
[16] "CP064128.1" "AL590842.1" "AE009952.1" "CP020414"   "AE017125"  
[21] "AL450380"   "CP007027.1" "AL123456.3" "AP018036"   "AP017922"  
[26] "CP007224"   "AP014696"   "BA000016.3" "HF930131"   "CP026932"  
[31] "AE014074"   "AE009949.1" "AP014596.1" "CP027540"   "CP066168"  
[36] "AP007209.1" "AE014613"   "AL157959"
```

But the errors "no such index at level 1" start here:

```
> # load accession #'s list into RBiotools; get associated organism data
> library(RBiotools)
> downloadGenome(access_nums1)
Initializing RBiotools
Error in GenomeSeqList[[aaa]] : no such index at level 1
> downloadGenome(access_nums2)
Error in GenomeSeqList[[aaa]] : no such index at level 1
> downloadGenome(access_nums3)
Error in GenomeSeqList[[aaa]] : no such index at level 1
> 
> #creating 16sRNA trees
> 
> dendrogram16S(
+   access_nums1[1],
+   treeType = "BEST",
+   leafLabel = "shortName",
+   plotIdentifier = "Single Species Genomes"
+ )
```

And errors that hinder the generation of the trees start here:

```
Creating dendrogram for 18 16S rRNA sequences
use default substitution matrix
Warning messages:
1: In if (grepl("^GCA_[[:digit:]]+", givenID)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (grepl("^GCF_[[:digit:]]+", givenID)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> 
> dendrogram16S(
+   access_nums2[2],
+   treeType = "BEST",
+   leafLabel = "shortName",
+   plotIdentifier = "Diverse Organism Genomes"
+ )
Error in if (grepl("^[[:upper:]]{4}$", givenID) || grepl("^[[:upper:]]{4}[[:digit:]]+",  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
> 
> dendrogram16S(
+   access_nums3[3],
+   treeType = ,
+   leafLabel = ,
+   plotIdentifier = "Single Species/Diverse Organism Combined Genomes"
+ )
Error in if (grepl("^[[:upper:]]{4}$", givenID) || grepl("^[[:upper:]]{4}[[:digit:]]+",  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
>
```

Thank you for any insight or help. Reading everything I can find related to possibly figuring out what can be done to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear, but I managed to fix this to print the trees I needed simply by changing the numbers "2" and "3" in the brackets of the 2nd and 3rd dendrogram function to "1" as well, like for the first dendrogram function:

```
dendrogram16S(access_nums1[1],
              treeType = "BEST",
              leafLabel = "shortName",
              plotIdentifier = "Single Species Genomes")

dendrogram16S(access_nums2[2],
              treeType = "BEST",
              leafLabel = "shortName",
              plotIdentifier = "Diverse Organism Genomes")

dendrogram16S(access_nums3[3],
              treeType = ,
              leafLabel = ,
              plotIdentifier = "Single Species/Diverse Organism Combined Genomes")
```

So instead, to be:

```
dendrogram16S(
  access_nums1[1],
  treeType = "BEST",
  leafLabel = "shortName",
  plotIdentifier = "Single Species Genomes"
)

dendrogram16S(
  access_nums2[1],
  treeType = "BEST",
  leafLabel = "fullName",
  plotIdentifier = "Diverse Species Genomes"
)

dendrogram16S(
  access_nums3[1],
  treeType = ,
  leafLabel = "fullName",
  plotIdentifier = "Combined Genomes"
)
```